# Posting a JSON object passed null rather than the object

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

When I using a literal stringified JSON object, all works as expected

**Index.cshtml (with literal ajax string $.ajax WORKS)**

```
var searchObject = new Object();
searchObject.Thing1 = '42';
searchObject.Thing2 = '43';
searchObject.Thing3 = '44';

var searchSerialized = JSON.stringify(searchObject);
alert(searchSerialized);
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/api/auditApi',
    type: "Post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{\'Thing1\':\'42\',\'Thing2\':\'43\',\'Thing3\':\'44\'}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
                       $(".kendoAudit").data("kendoGrid").dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: result });
                       $(".kendoAudit").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                       $(".kendoAudit").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
                   },
                   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                       alert('Status: ' + xhr.status + ', Error Thrown: ' + thrownError);
                   }
               });
```

However, when I use a serialized object created inline, it get null passed in to the post handler

**Index.cshtml (with object created inline and passed to $.ajax FAILS)**

```
var searchObject = new Object();
searchObject.Thing1 = '42';
searchObject.Thing2 = '43';
searchObject.Thing3 = '44';

var searchSerialized = JSON.stringify(searchObject);
alert(searchSerialized);
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/api/auditApi',
    type: "Post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: searchSerialized,  //I have tried concatenating with + '' also
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
                       $(".kendoAudit").data("kendoGrid").dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: result });
                       $(".kendoAudit").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                       $(".kendoAudit").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
                   },
                   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                       alert('Status: ' + xhr.status + ', Error Thrown: ' + thrownError);
                   }
               });
```

**Controller**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    try
    {
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        // throws because value is null.
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's something abundantly obvious I'm missing in the conversion here.

The debug line: `alert(searchSerialized);` displays what I'm expecting

Comment: Notice that your string literal does not contain valid JSON (which needs double quotes as delimiters), but just an object literal.

Comment: When you say *...it get null passed in to the post handler...* what do you mean by it? Are you saying the AJAX post is not sending any data? Or is the result in your success callback 'null'? (In the latter case you should check your API for the cause of the problem)

Comment: I receive null in the controller.  I will check the contents on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the data into model.
When serialized object is posted (which is no more string) MVC automatically bind it to the proper model.

Now change your action method something  like this.

```
    public class SearchObject
    {
        public int Thing1 { get; set; }
        public int Thing2 { get; set; }
        public int Thing3 { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(SearchObject searchObject)
    {
        return View();
    }
```